# Spawning multiple Balls in array js

Tags: javascript, canvas

Have not really used `array`'s before and i think i am making a mistake here
This code spawns the first ball with random color/vx etc, but no other ones,
I'm not sure which part is incorrect.

Error comes up in `ball.x += ball.vx` in the `animFrame()`  function.

Help?

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
var ball;
var numBalls = 5;

function Ball(radius, color) {
 this.x = 0;
 this.y = 0;
 this.vx = 0;
 this.vy = 0;
 this.radius = radius;
 this.color = random_color();
}

Ball.prototype.draw = function (ctx) {
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}; 

function random_color() {

  var letter = "0123456789ABCDEF".split(""); 
  var color = "#";                           
  for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){                
    color += letter[Math.round(Math.random()*15)]; 
  }
return color;
}


function init() {

  canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  balls = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i<numBalls; i++){
    ball = new Ball(Math.random() * 40 + 5, Math.random() * 0xffffff);
    ball.x = Math.random() * canvas.width / 2;
    ball.y = Math.random() * canvas.height / 2;
    ball.vx = Math.random() * 6 - 3;
    ball.vy = Math.random() * 6 - 3;
    ball.draw(ctx);
    balls.push(ball)
    animFrame();
}

function animFrame() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animFrame, canvas);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(var i = 0; i < numBalls; i++){
        var ball = balls[i];
        ball.x += ball.vx;       // Undefined here down.
        ball.y += ball.vy;
        if (ball.x + ball.radius > canvas.width || ball.x - ball.radius < 0)
            ball.vx = -ball.vx;
        if (ball.y + ball.radius > canvas.height || ball.y - ball.radius < 0)
            ball.vy = -ball.vy;

        ball.draw(ctx);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a lot of syntax errors in your code, that's why it doesn't work:

- It will work if you remove the animframe() call out of the for loop because that's whats making it only push one ball and stopping the for loop.
- You have also defined the animframe() function within init(), move it outside.
- Don't use var balls = new Array(), just use var balls = []; on the top of your code.

Here:

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
var ball;
var numBalls = 5;
var balls = [];

function Ball(radius, color) {
 this.x = 0;
 this.y = 0;
 this.vx = 0;
 this.vy = 0;
 this.radius = radius;
 this.color = random_color();
}

Ball.prototype.draw = function (ctx) {
ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}; 

function random_color() {

  var letter = "0123456789ABCDEF".split(""); 
  var color = "#";                           
  for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){                
    color += letter[Math.round(Math.random()*15)]; 
  }
  return color;
}


function init() {

  canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

for (var i = 0; i<numBalls; i++){
    ball = new Ball(Math.random() * 40 + 5, Math.random() * 0xffffff);
    ball.x = Math.random() * canvas.width / 2;
    ball.y = Math.random() * canvas.height / 2;
    ball.vx = Math.random() * 6 - 3;
    ball.vy = Math.random() * 6 - 3;
    ball.draw(ctx);
    balls.push(ball)
}
animFrame();
}

function animFrame() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animFrame, canvas);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(var i = 0; i < numBalls; i++){
        var ball = balls[i];
        ball.x += ball.vx;       // Undefined here down.
        ball.y += ball.vy;
        if (ball.x + ball.radius > canvas.width || ball.x - ball.radius < 0)
            ball.vx = -ball.vx;
        if (ball.y + ball.radius > canvas.height || ball.y - ball.radius < 0)
            ball.vy = -ball.vy;

    ball.draw(ctx);
    }
}
```